# Selective CSV Import

Tags: python, postgresql, csv

I have a CSV file export from a river temperature monitoring device; and I need to import it into a PostGres database via my application that uses Jython.
I know how to import the whole file, the problem is that there is a bunch of device information at the top of the csv and I do not need one of the columns. 
So I need to start at row 20, remove column B and remove the last row which is a statement that the data has ended. 
If anyone knows of a Python library capable of this any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly youre trying to convert a file with extra lines and columns into another file with no extra data so you can import it.

```py
import csv
```

I don't know how to use `csv` library which is included by default, but you can also try this:

```py
with open(inputFile) as if:            #will close f after ending
    with open(outputFile, mode='w') as of:
        lines = if.readLines()[19:-1]   #Ignore first 19 lines and last 1
        for line in lines:
            line = line.split('\t')    #Use the char/sequence that uses the CSV
            del line[1]                #I guess colB is at line[1]
            print(*line, sep='\t', file=of)
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: This was all written and executed in Python 2.7 with pandas 0.16.1

Ok so lets say that in this file you are using there are 4 columns titled A, B, C, and D. For example, each column just has a list of random numbers. You said you want to drop column B, and the first 19 rows and the last row for each column. Assuming this, try the following code (edited to fit your file, of course):

```
1    import pandas as pd
2    # set a variable to hold the imported csv file
3    hold = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv', header=0)
4    
5    # Now you want to take the relevant columns and add them to lists, so they can be manipulated
6    listA = hold['A']
7    listC = hold['C']
8    listD = hold['D']
9
10    # Now the first 19 rows and last row can be removed. Remember, due to indexing and having a header, the rows are offset by two not one
11    listA = listA[18:-1]
12    listB = listB[18:-1]
13    listC = listC[18:-1]
14
15    # adds each list back into what will become a new, edited, csv file. 
16    # pd.DataFrame is used to convert the lists into DataFrames, which is what pandas uses to write csv files.
17    # the first list cannot be named when it is added to the new list, not to worry this is fixed later on
18    new_file = pd.DataFrame(listA)
19    new_file['C'] = pd.DataFrame(listC)
20    new_file['D'] = pd.DataFrame(listD)
21
22    # this is where we add a name to the first list. When you rename the columns, you have to rename all the columns.
23    new_file.columns = ['A', 'C', 'D']
24
25    # here the new_file is put into a new csv file that has been edited to your specifications. setting index=False just makes it so there isn't an index added to the new csv file.
26    new_file.to_csv('new_file.csv', index=False)
```

That will do what you want. If you have more columns, just add more lists and make sure to use the same case when naming which columns you want to add to each list. Another thing to note is that if you need to change what rows are being removed, just change the indexes in lines 11-13